# Fastest Method for Counting Files in Directory Hierarchy

Tags: file, shell, filesystems

Quite simply I want to get a count of files in a directory (and all nested sub-directories) as quickly as possible.

I know how to do this using `find` paired with `wc -l` and similar methods, however these are extremely slow and they pass through each file entry in each directory and count them that way.

Is this the fastest method, or are there alternatives? For example; I don't need to find specific types of files, so I'm fine with grabbing symbolic-links, hidden files etc. if I can get the file-count more quickly by counting everything with no further processing involved.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest methos is to use `locate` + `wc` or similar. It can't be faster. The main disatvantage of the method that it counts not actual files, but the files that are in the locate's database. And this database can be alread 1 day old.

So it depends on your task: if it tolerates delays, I would prefer `locate`.

On my superfast SSD-based machine:

```
$ time find /usr | wc -l
156610

real    0m0.158s
user    0m0.076s
sys     0m0.072s

$ time locate /usr | wc -l
156612

real    0m0.079s
user    0m0.068s
sys     0m0.004s
```

On a normal machine the difference will be much much bigger.

How often is the locate database updated depends on the configuration of the host.
By default, it is updated each day (it is made using `cron`). But you can configure the system so, that the script will run every hour or even frquently. Of course, you can run it not periodically, but on demand (*I thank you William Pursell for the hint*).

Comment: The database can be updated as frequently as you desire, so you can make the maximum staleness much less than 1 day.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Yes of course, William, I perfectly understand that, the point is that if you need to update the database more often than runs `find`, this method is not that good anymore.

Comment: I'm not criticizing your solution and in fact gave you +1.  But the reader may be unaware that the frequency of runs can be modified.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Yes william, you are right (and thank you for the +1). I appreciate you hint, I think it deserves to be mentioned in the answer. I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script as an alternative:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'd="{}"; arr=($d/*); echo "$d:${#arr[@]}"' \;
```

In my quick basic testing it came faster than `wc -l`